# Odoo: ask delete reason on unlink method?

Tags: odoo-9

How I ask reason on unlink method. I tried to call wizard method. But it's not working because it has validation/from python code/.
How can I ask delete reason?

Answer (score 0):

you can override unlink method to only fire-up a wizard asking for the reason, and only when the user sets the reason you make the actual unlinking.